# Inserting tuples into Ocaml list

Tags: list, ocaml

I'm slightly confused because the compiler tells me that `1, [5;2]` 
is not a tuple for both cases :

`(1,[5;2])::[6,[5;1]; 2,[16;1]]`

this doesn't work (why ?)

`1,[5;2]::[6,[5;1]; 2,[16;1]]`

I'm asking this because I need to solve my problem :

```
type node = int
type edge = node * node
type graph = (node * node list) list

let has_node g n = List.exists ((=) n) g

let insert_node g n = 
    if has_node g n then g else (n, [])::g (*here is where the compiler complains*)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`::` has higher precedence than `,`. Therefore, your second line does not define the same value as the first one. Instead it defines `1,([5;2]::[6,[5;1]; 2,[16;1]])`.

The problem with your code is, that `has_node` expects the list `g` to contain elements of the type of `n` while `(n,[])` is of a different type.